# How to add additional info to an image?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am new to React and Ionic and builded the Ionic React photo gallery app with the help of [this ionic tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/your-first-app). Now I also want to add additional info like its date, its location, some inputfields,... to the image when it is displayed but I just did not figure out how.

This is the code from the tutorial:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { isPlatform } from '@ionic/react';

import { Camera, CameraResultType, CameraSource, Photo } from '@capacitor/camera';
import { Filesystem, Directory } from '@capacitor/filesystem'
import { Storage } from '@capacitor/storage'
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import internal from "assert";
import { defaultMaxListeners } from "stream";

const PHOTO_STORAGE = "photos";

export function usePhotoGallery() {

  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState<UserPhoto[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadSaved = async () => {
      const {value} = await Storage.get({key: PHOTO_STORAGE });

      const photosInStorage = (value ? JSON.parse(value) : []) as UserPhoto[];
      // If running on the web...
      if (!isPlatform('hybrid')) {
        for (let photo of photosInStorage) {
          const file = await Filesystem.readFile({
            path: photo.filepath,
            directory: Directory.Data
          });
          // Web platform only: Load the photo as base64 data
          photo.webviewPath = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${file.data}`;
        }
      }
      setPhotos(photosInStorage);
    };
    loadSaved();
  }, []);

  const takePhoto = async () => {
    const cameraPhoto = await Camera.getPhoto({
      resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
      source: CameraSource.Camera,
      quality: 100
    });
    const fileName = new Date().getTime() + '.jpeg';
    const savedFileImage = await savePicture(cameraPhoto, fileName);
    const newPhotos = [savedFileImage, ...photos];
    setPhotos(newPhotos);
    Storage.set({key: PHOTO_STORAGE,value: JSON.stringify(newPhotos)});

  };

  const savePicture = async (photo: Photo, fileName: string): Promise<UserPhoto> => {
    let base64Data: string;
    // "hybrid" will detect Cordova or Capacitor;
    if (isPlatform('hybrid')) {
      const file = await Filesystem.readFile({
        path: photo.path!
      });
      base64Data = file.data;
    } else {
      base64Data = await base64FromPath(photo.webPath!);
    }
    const savedFile = await Filesystem.writeFile({
      path: fileName,
      data: base64Data,
      directory: Directory.Data
    });

    if (isPlatform('hybrid')) {
      // Display the new image by rewriting the 'file://' path to HTTP
      // Details: https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/webview#file-protocol
      return {
        filepath: savedFile.uri,
        webviewPath: Capacitor.convertFileSrc(savedFile.uri),
      };
    }
    else {
      // Use webPath to display the new image instead of base64 since it's
      // already loaded into memory
      return {
        filepath: fileName,
        webviewPath: photo.webPath
      };
    }
  };

  const deletePhoto = async (photo: UserPhoto) => {
    // Remove this photo from the Photos reference data array
    const newPhotos = photos.filter(p => p.filepath !== photo.filepath);

    // Update photos array cache by overwriting the existing photo array
    Storage.set({key: PHOTO_STORAGE, value: JSON.stringify(newPhotos) });

    // delete photo file from filesystem
    const filename = photo.filepath.substr(photo.filepath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    await Filesystem.deleteFile({
      path: filename,
      directory: Directory.Data
    });
    setPhotos(newPhotos);
  };
  
  return {
    deletePhoto,
    photos,
    takePhoto
  };
}

export interface UserPhoto {
  filepath: string;
  webviewPath?: string;
}

export async function base64FromPath(path: string): Promise<string> {
  const response = await fetch(path);
  const blob = await response.blob();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.onload = () => {
      if (typeof reader.result === 'string') {
        resolve(reader.result);
      } else {
        reject('method did not return a string')
      }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
}
```

I managed to get the date and location with the [Geolocation Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation) but I have no clue how to bind it to the taken photo...

I assume that I have to add the desired data via `function base64FromPath()` for web and `const file = await Filesystem.readFile()` for mobile? And afterwards display with the `export interface UserPhoto` part but I am completly lost and do not know where to start. Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way might not be the prettiest or directest but it seems to work for me.

Within the `takePhoto` function I get the location and date and then pass it on via the `savePicture` function. Inside the `savePicture` function I return `latitude`, `longitude` and `time` and therefore can access it through the `loadSaved` function within the `photo` object. Inside `interface UserPhoto` the 3 variables need also to be declared.

Here is the updated code if somebody would like to make a suggestion:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { isPlatform } from '@ionic/react';


import { Geolocation, Geoposition } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { Camera, CameraResultType, CameraSource, CameraDirection, Photo } from '@capacitor/camera';
import { Filesystem, Directory } from '@capacitor/filesystem'
import { Storage } from '@capacitor/storage'
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import { stringify } from "querystring";

const PHOTO_STORAGE = "photos";
export function usePhotoGallery() {

  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState<UserPhoto[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadSaved = async () => {
      const {value} = await Storage.get({key: PHOTO_STORAGE });

      const photosInStorage = (value ? JSON.parse(value) : []) as UserPhoto[];
      // If running on the web...
      if (!isPlatform('hybrid')) {
        for (let photo of photosInStorage) {
          const file = await Filesystem.readFile({
            path: photo.filepath,
            directory: Directory.Data
          });
          // Web platform only: Load the photo as base64 data
          photo.webviewPath = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${file.data}`;
        }
      }
      setPhotos(photosInStorage);
    };
    loadSaved();
  }, []);

  const takePhoto = async () => {
    const position = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
    const latitude = position.coords.latitude
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude
    const time = new Date(position.timestamp).toLocaleString()
    
    const cameraPhoto = await Camera.getPhoto({
      resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
      source: CameraSource.Camera,
      direction: CameraDirection.Rear,
      quality: 100
    });
    const fileName = new Date().getTime() + '.jpeg';
    const savedFileImage = await savePicture(cameraPhoto, fileName, latitude, longitude, time);
    const newPhotos = [savedFileImage, ...photos];
    setPhotos(newPhotos);
    Storage.set({key: PHOTO_STORAGE,value: JSON.stringify(newPhotos)});
  };

  const savePicture = async (photo: Photo, fileName: string, latitude: number, longitude: number, time:string): Promise<UserPhoto> => {
    let base64Data: string;
    // "hybrid" will detect Cordova or Capacitor;
    if (isPlatform('hybrid')) {
      const file = await Filesystem.readFile({
        path: photo.path!
      });
      base64Data = file.data;
    } else {
      base64Data = await base64FromPath(photo.webPath!);
    }
    console.log("base64Data")
    console.log(base64Data)
    let savedFile = await Filesystem.writeFile({
      path: fileName,
      data: base64Data,
      directory: Directory.Data
    });
    console.log(savedFile)

    if (isPlatform('hybrid')) {
      // Display the new image by rewriting the 'file://' path to HTTP
      // Details: https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/webview#file-protocol
      return {
        filepath: savedFile.uri,
        webviewPath: Capacitor.convertFileSrc(savedFile.uri),
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude,
        time: time
      };
    }
    else {
      // Use webPath to display the new image instead of base64 since it's
      // already loaded into memory
      return {
        filepath: fileName,
        webviewPath: photo.webPath,
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude,
        time: time
      };
    }
  };

  const deletePhoto = async (photo: UserPhoto) => {
    // Remove this photo from the Photos reference data array
    const newPhotos = photos.filter(p => p.filepath !== photo.filepath);

    // Update photos array cache by overwriting the existing photo array
    Storage.set({key: PHOTO_STORAGE, value: JSON.stringify(newPhotos) });

    // delete photo file from filesystem
    const filename = photo.filepath.substr(photo.filepath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    await Filesystem.deleteFile({
      path: filename,
      directory: Directory.Data
    });
    setPhotos(newPhotos);
  };

  return {
    deletePhoto,
    photos,
    takePhoto
  };
}

export interface UserPhoto {
  filepath: string;
  webviewPath?: string;
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  time: string;
}

export async function base64FromPath(path: string): Promise<string> {
  const response = await fetch(path);
  const blob = await response.blob();
  //const blob = new Blob(neu)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    console.log(reader)
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.onload = () => {
      if (typeof reader.result === 'string') {
        resolve(reader.result);
      } else {
        reject('method did not return a string')
      }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
}
```

To access is in my UI.tsx I use eg `{photo.latitude}` to display the taken latitude value